# What is a good Version Control GUI Client for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, gui, version-control

I find there are too few for SVN, so I might switch to another. Right now I'm using [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/), an SVN nautilus integration. Very similar to tortoiseSVN but with bugs/beta/alpha feel. I need something much more stable, more features, and good for SOLO development. There will be no other team members in the future, so that needs to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Try [SmartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse for Ecplise isn't bad. There's also the prospect of using KDESVN, if you use KDE. Another suggestion would be using git-svn and maybe checking out some of their clients?

You might want to post to stackoverflow or search there for better answers.